# Drag and drop from popover iOS 13

Tags: drag-and-drop

I cannot drag and drop from a TableView Controller to a textView in my main view while using a popover segue. However, it works fine using a show segue. I found that I could easily drag and drop (app to app) to and from a table view in another app. Any insights would be appreciated. I am a novice. Thanks. Xcode 11.4, swift 4.2, iOS 13.4, Mac OS 10.15.4

Comment: I've been doing this for 10 years and I still can't work out why this is happening :)